# Site is not accessible by webscrapers

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, http-status-code-404

The website I am using is being scraped with wrong information. (metatag checker) Namely the information when looking for a domain of my hosting company (my host name service provider). I can totally not understand why. I want to be able to share my site on social media but somehow it is not available. I really don't know what is going on.. Can someone please help?

The following links show what I mean:

https://rankingapp.metatags.nl/nl/reports/mysite.nl
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=www.mysite.nl

And this is my website: http://www.mysite.nl

Comment: You have to give us more information. What do you expect to happen and what do happen?

Comment: OR possibly https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ . Be sure to read their help for on-topic Qs as well. Good luck.

Comment: Facebook prefers IPv6 over IPv4 when available, and in the debug tool output you see _“Server IP: 2a02:2268:ffff:ffff::4”_ - so go check/have checked that your DNS configuration is correct.

Comment: @CBroe thanks allot! this happened to be the answer. So happy! :) Perhaps an idea to post your comment as answer?

Comment: You have errors in your HTML too. Validate your code: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook prefers IPv6 over IPv4 when available, and in the debug tool output you see

> Server IP: 2a02:2268:ffff:ffff::4

So go check/have checked that your DNS configuration is correct.

---

Having the DNS wrongly resolve the IPv6 address of the domain to the "main domain" of a shared(?) hosting account is a common cause for such problems. End users are still largely "on IPv4" when they're browsing the net, so real users hardly ever notice such issues - but when the Facebook scraper comes along and wants to request the page via IPv6, it goes wrong ...